# Limit problem: $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$ as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: limits, radicals

I know it is extremely basic but I am stuck on this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$$

I have no idea how to proceed. Hints or full solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$$