# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = 0$?

Tags: limits

Ofcourse I can see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = 0$ just by looking aat it, but how can I prove it in the right way?

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545704/show-that-sqrtn1-sqrtn-to0
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447360/limit-problem-sqrtx1-sqrtx-as-x-approaches-infinity
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582826/prove-that-the-limit-of-sqrtn1-sqrtn-is-zero

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Use $a-b = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}.$

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? Just for the laughs?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Use $0 < \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$