# Find limit $\lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} -\sqrt{2x^{4}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

$\displaystyle \lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}}\displaystyle -\sqrt{2x^{4}}\right)$

$\displaystyle \lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} -\sqrt{2x^{4}}\right)$$\displaystyle =\displaystyle \lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} -\sqrt{2x^{4}}\right)\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }\right)}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }} =$

$\displaystyle =\lim\limits _{x\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} -x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }}$

What is the next step should be? Please help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025375/finding-lim-limits-n%E2%86%92%E2%88%9En3-sqrtn2-sqrtn41-n-sqrt2

Answer (score 6):

Now, use that
$$\sqrt{x^4+1}-x^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the trick twice for the numerator to obtain

$$\dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} -x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }}=\dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} -x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }}\cdot \dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} +x^{4}}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} +x^{4}}=$$

$$=\dfrac{x^4}{\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }\right)\left(x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} +x^{4}\right)}\sim\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2 x^2}\to 0$$

Comment: @user376343 Opsss yes of course I fix the typo! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}}-\sqrt{2x^4}=
\dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} -x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4}}}=
\dfrac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} -x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4} \ }}\cdot\frac{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} +x^{4}}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1} +x^{4}}\\=\frac{x^4}{\big(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}} +\sqrt{2x^{4}}\big)\big(x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}+x^4\big)}\\=\frac{1}{\big(\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{1+x^{-4}}} +\sqrt{2}\big)\big(\sqrt{x^{4}+1}+x^2\big)}\,\to\,0
$$

Comment: Are you sure, Yiorgos?

Comment: You have divided twice by $x^4$.

Comment: @gimusi You are right! - Corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using substitution $x=\cot t$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^{4} +x^{2}\sqrt{x^{4} +1}}-\sqrt{2x^{4}}\right) 
&=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos^2t+\cos t}-\sqrt{2\cos^2t}}{\sin t} \\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\cos t(1-\cos t)}{\sin t(\sqrt{\cos^2t+\cos t}+\sqrt{2\cos^2t})} \\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\cos t}{\sqrt{\cos^2t+\cos t}+\sqrt{2\cos^2t}}\dfrac{2\sin^2\frac{t}{2}}{\frac{t^2}{2}}\dfrac{t}{\sin t}\dfrac{t}{2} \\
&=\color{blue}{0}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you precise? How is $x=\cos t$ with $t\to 0$ if $x\to \infty$?

Comment: @user376343 It's impossible when $x\to\infty$ then $t\to0$ with $x=\cos t$.

Comment: When $t \to 0$ then $\cos t \to 1$ therefore I find you substitution mysterious...

Comment: Of course it is :)

Comment: @user376343, a letter makes a difference here: $\cos t$ and $\cot t$.

Comment: Thanks. So, there was a typo.